# We need no [details]

Tags: discussion, support, tags

The [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details) tag is vague and has no description. There are many uses. I think the main (and intended) one is the HTML5 `<details>` tag. Other than that, it is used:

- for questions about [configuration details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687366/where-can-i-find-websphere-configuration-files)
- requesting [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541511/reading-and-saving-music-meta-data) about something
- for no apparent reason ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609726/data-usage-during-hotspot))

Most questions tagged with [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/details) have "details" in their title (a clear indication it probably shouldn't be used):

- [Stop browser from filling textboxes with details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630986/stop-browser-from-filling-textboxes-with-details)
- [Android launch applications detail page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238946/android-launch-applications-detail-page)
- [iOS facebookSDK get user full details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383578/ios-facebooksdk-get-user-full-details)

What should we do about it?

Comment: Don't you mean we need *no* details?

Comment: Oops. _________